# Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate with empty -fields parameter not working?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to use a modern SPO team site als a template for similar projects with a prefilled task list (very similar projects).

I created a site template with Save-PnPProvisioningTemplate and tried to add the Data rows with Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate and a empty -fields parameter but that does not work. I need exact the same task list as in the template.

Does anybody know if this is a bug?

I already discussed on this particular topic right here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/211447/copy-spo-team-site-with-task-list-contensrow-data.html?childToView=215328#answer-215328 but wanted to check here before I post a bug on github.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpdatarowstoprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps) for the parameter fields:

> The fields to retrieve. If not specified all fields will be loaded in
> the returned list object.

So, if you leave the -fields parameter empty, it will load all fields including default system fields like Created, Created By, Modified... These default fields are generated by SharePoint and could not be added/edit manually. I think that's the reason that would not work.

So you need to specify the fields parameter which can be edited by end users. Like
column `duedate, Title, startdate` in the command.

Note: you need to use the internal name of the column, for the description column in the task list. The internal name is Body.

You could change field in the template `<FieldRef Name="Description" />` to `<FieldRef Name="Body" />`. Maybe it would work fo you
[image]

Comment: You are right about the documentation, but that's not working. If I leave the -fields parameter empty no data rows are added (which I think is a bug) or like you posted because they are generated by SharePoint.

Ok, I understand that I need the internal name, but the strange thing is, that the names are added by Save-PnPProvisioningTemplate and description is the only one that does not use the correct internal name, so that I always have to manually correct that name.

Do you have an idea where I can get a complete english list of all the internal names?

Comment: You could use the command  Get-PnPField -List "Task1"  to get the internal names of fields.

Comment: Nice, this gives me a complete list with Title, InternalName and Id. Why do some of the Fields start with an underscore e.g. _ModerationStatus, _EditMenuTableEnd, ...? Is there an easy why to filter those out and use the the InternalName as the input list for the -Fields parameter? I guess I have to filter the output with a where statment und pipe it into the parameter.